# How could I get the current day and current time with AM/PM of computer using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show current day and time(HH:MM) with AM/PM on my page. How to achieve this task in jQuery. I have done above thing using JavaScript but I just want to know how to do this task in jQuery easily as per the require.

Comment: When writing a question please don't put the content into a code tag, it's really annoying to read.
At the same time JQuery is nothing but a library written in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is just a Javascript library. It doesn't have any special methods for handling dates, so it's no help for you in that aspect.

The only thing that it can help you with is to display the date once you have formatted it into a string. Example:

```
var formattedDate = SomeMethodToGetTheFormattedDate();
$('#IdOfElementForDisplayingDate').text(formattedDate);
```